# How to insert space in loop in Jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have the following (unfinished) code:

```
for file in files
            a= file
```

How to get space between all `A` tags?

Comment: What do you mean by `A` tags? Seems like all you're doing here is assigning the valur of file to `a` (which is just a variable and not a tag).

Comment: @DakshShah in `HTML` this appers as `A` tag with filename inside (with no link information). I don't know why. Looks like this done by Jade engine :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different approaches to this. One is to add an inline space character like I have done below. Please note the `|` character and 2 spaces following that. One space is to separate the content from this character and the 2nd space is the actual space that is rendered in the final html.

```
- var files = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"];

for file in files
            |  
            a= file
```

Another approach (which I prefer) is to render these without spaces and then add some margin/padding using css.